# Como reproduzir som em android

Tags: java, android

Bom dia, gostaria de saber como posso fazer um código para que ao clicar em um botão ele reproduza um som

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No método do seu botão use o seguinte código:

```
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            mp.release();
        }

    });   
    mp.start();
```

**Notas:**

- Substitua `MainActivity`em `MainActivity.this` pelo nome da sua activity
- Substitua `sound` em `R.raw.sound` pelo nome do arquivo do som que quer reproduzir. Esse arquivo tem de estar na pasta `res\raw`

Answer (score 1):

[image: Crie a pasta raw como mostra a imagem..]

Então acrescente esse código:

```
private void playSound() {
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
   mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Coloquei seu áudio na pasta raw com o nome **beep** ou altere o ´beep´ pelo nome do seu arquivo no código acima.

Agora é só chamar o método **playSound()** no evento OnClickListener do seu botão.