# Programando com sons para android

Tags: android, áudio

Quero programar sons no Android mas não estou conseguindo. Tentei a API java sound mas o Android studio não reconhece. Quero utilizar MIDI também. Sei que tem o pacote android.media.midi mas ele só funciona pra versões do android acima da 23. Quero uma solução para todas as versões. Alguém pode me ajudar?

---

Muito obrigado a todos pela atenção.
O código do que eu quero fazer segue abaixo:

```
    ShortMessage myMsg = new ShortMessage();
    // Play the note Middle C (60) moderately loud
    // (velocity = 93)on channel 4 (zero-based).

    myMsg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 4, 60, 93);
    Synthesizer synth = null;
    synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
    Receiver synthRcvr = null;
    synthRcvr = synth.getReceiver();
    synthRcvr.send(myMsg, -1); // -1 means no time stamp
```

Ou seja, quero editar messagens MIDI.
O que eu não entendo é por que o Android Studio não reconhece a API Java Sound (que eu estou utilizando). Alguém sabe?
Oi Márcio Oliveira. Sobre a library que você postou acho que esta incompleta. Não tem, por exemplo, o file ShortMessage.java.

Comment: Veja se é isto que procura: [Como tocar um som usando o Mediaplayer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97263/2541) e [Como reproduzir som em android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94187/2541)

Comment: @suiça, pode postar o que ja tentou fazer ?

Comment: Você quer reproduzir arquivos *mid* ou quer usar/controlar dispositivos *midi* ligados a um dispositivo Android?

Comment: Se especificar melhor o que precisa, talvez eu possa te ajudar a criar sinteticamente os áudios que precisa sem a necessidade de uso de lib, mas "programar sons para android" é muito vago :-(

Answer (score 2):

A classe MediaPlayer reproduz MIDI sem problemas pois o formato MIDI é suportado nativamente pelo Android conforme documentação oficial:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

Eis um exemplo simples com MediaPlayer (coloque um arquivo midi na pasta "res/raw"):

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.midi_sound);
mediaPlayer.start();

//Se quiser pausar
mediaPlayer.pause()

// Se quiser avançar para os primeiros 30 segundos
mediaPlayer.seekTo(30000);
```

Se quiser fazer coisas mais avançadas como editar os MIDI's, usar periféricos, etc, só conheço a classe android.media.midi mesmo que foi introduzida apenas na API 23 (Marshmallow). Pode dar uma olhada nessa library aqui, mas nunca usei:

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1988